# is it possible to use pig built in function inside pig java udf

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig and writing java UDF for different operations which already exists in builtin package but the datatype does not match when called from application.
So I need to wrap pig built in functions of correct datatype from user defined datatypes.

Please suggest.

Comment: No.Can you provide more information on the datatype you are using in PIG and the PIG function that you would like to use.

Comment: I don't think the answer to this question will solve your problem, but you could of course ask a different question that can be answered better.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution that you propose is not possible.

Though you did not ask this (and did not provide relevant information to enable people to be more specific), it is probably possible to solve your problem with a different solution.